# Is there any free way to setup development environment for Windows CE 5?

Tags: windows-ce

I got Windows CE 5 device, and I tried to make apps for it.

But I had to install VS 2005 Professional which is non-free one. I didn't wanted to do that.
What I want to ask is, is there (free) alternative for this?

Comment: Try asking at [softwarerecs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Visual Studio Community...

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember, [Microsoft Embedded Visual C++](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16683) is free as in beer, and allows you to write C/C++ applications for CE 5.0.